# Star Trek TOS Episode "City on the Edge of Forever", how many went down to the alien planet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

For all intents and purposes the question that I pose is simple and to the point.  Including McCoy as 1, how many people from the Enterprise beamed down to the alien planet.

Comment: There was already an away team examining the Guardian portal when McCoy beamed down, wasn't there?  A scientist and half a dozen red shirts, as I recall.

Answer (score 6):

7.

As seen in the below image, there are 2 redshirts, Scotty, Uhura, Kirk, McCoy and Spock.

These are the ones specifically from the Enterprise.

[image]

Comment: Poor Sulu left all alone on the bridge! (Chekov hadn't joined yet).

Comment: @Thunderforge - I was about to ask about Chekhov, but remembered COTEOF was first season. No Chekhov yet.

Answer (score 6):

### Kirk, Spock, Scott, Uhura, two security guards and Dr. McCoy.

According to the 'script only the party of 6 beamed down, after McCoy.

> CHIEF [OC]: Captain, Doctor McCoy has beamed himself down to the planet.
>   SPOCK: And the transporter at that time, Captain, was focused on the centre of the time disturbance.
>   KIRK: So whatever's down there, McCoy is in the heart of it. Set up a landing party. Let's go get him. Kirk out.
>
> [Planet surface]
>
> (The landing party is **Kirk, Spock, Scott, Uhura and two security guards**. Among remains of fluted columns and fragments of Greek-style buildings is an irregular dough-nut shaped object with lights in it.)
>   <sub>[City on the Edge of Forever 'script - Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/28.htm)</sub>

Memory Alpha [identifies](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_City_on_the_Edge_of_Forever_(episode)#Act_One) one of the security guards as [Galloway](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galloway), but in the 'script Galloway is last mentioned shortly before the party beams down, it was him who found the unconscious transport officer.

> [Transporter room]
>   GALLOWAY: Security 054, sir. We just found the transport chief injured.
>   <sub>[City on the Edge of Forever 'script - Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/28.htm)</sub>

Comment: Just a note: Chakoteya is a transcript, not a script.

Comment: @JohnP subtle changes make all the difference ;)